# Big external JSON file or littles JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, file

I have a simple question with a complex answer I guess.
So lets say we have a big external JSON file that holds alot of data,
for example (consider this as a big file) :
50 students and every student has 100 properties in it.
is it better to save an one external JSON file with 50 object (the number of students).
Or to make 50 external JSON files (every file is consider to be a student)?
and how can I determine which method to choose?

Comment: That "big" file is quite small. Anyway, KISS (one file/resource) until there is a need to do otherwise (i.e. support pagination or individual lookups) - and this "otherwise" will likely involve server processing, not manually dividing of JSON files.

Comment: It's small. I work with 8000 lines, with 10 values each. It works.

Comment: I wrote  on my example "consider it as a big file". If you consider a big file to be 1000000 items its also fine with me. My question is theortical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of the thumb is that a handshake that happend on every request over the Web is time cost comparable to the actual sending of data. That speaks for one large file.

On the other hand, it sounds like you are considering not displaying all data at once, this may be a case for requesting data as needed.

There is, however, a compromise. You can load a bit of data that you immediately need on page load and then, ajax the rest of it in while user is reading the page. Cache all of the above in memory or client DB and you can guarantee avoiding performance lag from that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is: you should try both and measure them in a real environment (ie., on production hardware with your browser).

The fake guess-y answer is: the larger file will probably yield slightly less latency when loading your page, assuming it is blocking load completion in a meaningful way.